# How to use python to check whether maven is installed

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script to build a project with multiple technology stack. I need to check whether all prerequisites are ready and Maven is one of the prerequisite.

Normally, the Maven tutorial will ask the user to set an environment variable `M2_HOME` and add `%M2_HOME%/bin` to the path.

It's easy to check the environment variable with code below,

```
if 'M2_HOME' not in os.environ:
    print('Install maven firstly')
```

However, if the user doesn't set `M2_HOME` as an environment variable but adds `pache-maven-x.x.x\bin` to the path, it can still be thought as Maven being installed successfully and I think the latter is more comprehensive.

**So, here comes the question**: How can I use Python to check whether Maven is installed?

In my view, it's possible to launch `mvn` as a process from Python and check what the output is, for example by calling `mvn -v`. Any other suggestion?

Comment: does it have to be platform independent? i.e. run on any OS

Comment: @con Only windows is OK to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`shutil.which`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which) command

```
import shutil
if not shutil.which("mvn"):
    print('Install maven firstly')
```

edit:
For python2.7 you can use `distutils.spawn.find_executable` instead:

```
from distutils.spawn import find_executable
if not find_executable("mvn"):
    print('Install maven firstly')
```

Comment: Let me try it and give you feedback later

Comment: It's required to use Python 2.7 and I don't find which method in shutil, I guess it's python 3.+ stuff. Right?

Comment: For python2.7 you can use: from distutils.spawn import find_executable
>>> find_executable("mvn")

Comment: The find_executable('mvn') is None even if 'mvn' is available with built-in command line.

Comment: Although it doesn't solve my problem completely, it could still be a solution for most scenario, I'd like to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
# tested on windows 7, python 2.7.13 
import subprocess
import os


def version_available(cmd):
    try:
        # prints version and returns 0 if successulf
        output = subprocess.call([cmd, "--version"])
        return output == 0
    except OSError as e:
        # handle file not found error.
        if e.errno == os.errno.ENOENT:
            print("error please install " + cmd)
            return False
        else:
          # Something else went wrong, raise the exception
          raise

version_available("mvn")    # returns False, prints error please install mvn
version_available("python") # returns True,  prints Python 2.7.13
```

Comment: Thanks for this wrapper but it still doesn't work for mvn. I have installed it and can get output when I type "mvn --version" manually on cmd.exe. I upvoted this answer cause it can be a solution for other exe in limited scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the terminal command `which mvn`, if the response is `mvn not found` then you should install it.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["which", "mvn"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.communicate()
```

then compare the output

Comment: which isn't available on windows though. A better approach would be to check that mvn -v returns some version number (possibly compared by regex)

Comment: Let me try it and give you feedback later

Comment: As @con-- said, I'm using windows and `which` is available.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't specified in the question. Anyway, you can use the same approach with a different command, such as a simple `mvn` and check from the output if the command is found or not.